# SWRevealViewController and Tab Bar Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I'm trying to develop my first app. I recognize this is probably an easy problem (and that i'm likely not stating my question clearly) so any help is more than appreciated.

I've got a storyboard that uses SWRevealController. The sw_rear panel that gets swiped out from the side has a few options in table form. One of the options is connected to a UITabBarController. There are three tabs. The implementation file for each of the 3 views has 
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
to allow me to do a pan gesture to bring back the sw_rear panel.

When I compile, everything works well the first time. i can go to tab 1 and swipe and the panel appears. i go to tab 2 and swipe and the panel appears. but then, if i go back to panel 1 and swipe....nothing!

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Thanks,
Rich

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this code  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer]; in viewWillAppear Method

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem. Now, not to press my luck but would you mind telling me why i needed to have that line in the viewWillAppear method as opposed to the viewDidLoad method?

Comment: because viewdidload method is executes only once and viewwillappear executes whenever you open that view

Comment: that's correct but , already we've added in viewdidload. so it persists till the viewcontroller is alive. we do we need to add everytime in viewwill appear whenever it appears..?